# Javascript how to pass index value of a class to another class inside a function?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm trying to preview image in specific class that has the same index value of another class, from where the user selects an image. 
So far I have done this. When I give a specific value to the output class index the image shows up in that specific class

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].onchange = function() {
            output[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
     }
}
```

However when I try to pass the 'i' variable to that class's index the code doesn't work.

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].onchange = function() {
            output[i].src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
     }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to pass the i to the function, like:`input[i].onchange = function(i) {` ?

Comment: I did. Didn.t seem to work.

Comment: @GarbageCollector, did you try it yourself? that doesn't work.

Comment: @MahadiDJIT, please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you have used a `closure` function.When the function is `invoked`, it is created a single `context`.

Read more about, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

One method is to use [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {        
    (function(index){
        input[index].onchange = function() {
            output[index].src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }(i));
}
```

Here is an example where `closures` are used in `wrong` way.

```js
var input=document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {   
        input[i].onclick = function() {
            console.log(i);
        }
}
```

```html
<button class="abc">Button1</button>
<button class="abc">Button2</button>
<button class="abc">Button3</button>
```

As you can see, anything `button` you clicked, `console.log` display `3`.

> Why it is this behavior ?

It is created a single `context`. When `for` `loop` is finished, the value of `i` remain `3` and whenever you `clicked` one button, this value is display in `console`.

> How can we resolve this problem ?

One method is to use [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), as I mentioned above.

```js
var input=document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {   
      (function(index){
        input[index].onclick = function() {
            console.log(index);
        }
      }(i)); 

}
```

```html
<button class="abc">Button1</button>
<button class="abc">Button2</button>
<button class="abc">Button3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks man. with a little modification it worked!

Comment: You're welcome ! don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people.